# Getting the x-coordinate of the n-th element of Rafael.js Set of Text elements

Tags: javascript, svg

I have made a Rafael.js set of text elements with the following code.

```
var eltext = Canvas.paper.set();
text=Canvas.paper.text(xPos, yPos, character).attr({"font-size": fontSize});
eltext.push(text);
```

I would now like to get the x-coordinate of the first text element (actually a character) of the set.  I tried

```
firstChar=eltext.at(0);
xPos=firstChar.x;
```

but it did not give a believable value.  I also tried

```
firstChar=eltext.at(0);
xPos=firstChar.getAttribute('x');
```

but got a syntax error.  I also found that eltext.shift() gives a syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My syntax was wrong.  This works.

```
firstChar=eltext[0];
characterPos=firstChar.attr('x');
```